# Reactive evenly sized grouped divs

Tags: html, css

I have an array of N boolean values. I want to display them in a line like below, `true` being blue and `false` being orange.

[image]

I also want to group each block of like values, so I can generate a tooltip, the resulting html might look something like:

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="group" title="Group 1">
    <div class="item blue">
    <div class="item blue">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="group" title="Group 2">
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

There will be N `div.items`, and each of these should be the same width. I also want the `div.line` element to reactively occupy the full width of it's parent, and have groups/items enlarge reactively with it.

I have it working without the `div.group` using the following CSS, however I can't figure out how to extend it to work appropriately with groups.

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

How can I accomplish this with pure CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You might set [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#contents) for the `group` class. This way the `group` will act like it isn't there, so the items will respect the `flex` property of the `line` element.

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.group {
  display: contents;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however it seems to limit the usefulness of the .group class i.e. .group:hover { opacity: .5; } doesn't seem to affect the content. Other ideas would be welcome.

Comment: You are right, good point. I think this won't have a solution without using JS at this moment. The only solution I can think of is using [subgrid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid), but this isn't supported by all browsers.